# How do I add text to the right of this map using HTML?

Tags: html

`I am coding a website for a company and they would like their company hours to be on the home page. I added a map to the site, but cannot figure out how to add text directly to the right of the map. I have tried several variations of float: right and float: left but nothing has worked. Thanks!

```
<section id = "map">
<div class = "container">
<h2>Find Us Today!</h2>
<div class="mapouter">
<div class="gmap_canvas">
<iframe width="600" height="500" id="gmap_canvas" 
src="https://maps.google.com/maps? 
q=
5217%20Dominion%20Drive%20Dublin%2C%20VA%20&t=&z=13&ie=UTF8&iwloc=
&output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" 
marginwidth="0"></iframe>
<a href="https://www.embedgooglemap.net"></a>
</div>
<style = float.left>.mapouter{text- 
align:right;height:500px;width:600px;}.gmap_canvas 
{overflow:hidden;background:none!important;height:500px;width:600px;} 
</style>
</div>
</div>
</section>

<section id = "contact">
<div class = "container">
<h3>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h3>
<p>5217 Dominion Drive <br>
  Dublin, Virginia, 24084<br>
  <br>

<h3>Contact Us</h3>
<p>(540)-XXXXXXXX</p>

<h3>Hours</h3>
<p>Monday: 9AM to 5PM<br>
 Tuesday: 9AM to 5PM<br>
 Wednesday: 9AM to 5PM<br>
 Thursday: 9AM to 5PM<br>
 Friday: 9AM to 5PM<br>
 Saturday: 9AM to 5PM<br>
 Sunday: 9AM to 5PM<br>
 </p>
 </div>
 </section>
```

[I would like to add text to the right of the map with company hours and contact information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYcCV.jpg)

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Added the code. The first section adds the map correctly to the page, I would like to add the second section of text to the right of the code, in the whitespace shown in the image

Comment: Also I apologize for the lack of information in the OP, this is my first time asking on stackoverflow. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What are you trying to put next to `.mapouter`, `#contact`? `<style = float.left>` is not even valid html. If you float `.mapouter` & `#contact` left you should get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would need to see some code. This sounds like a CSS issue. Are you using a style sheet or just inline coding your styles? What happens to the text that you are adding? Does it get hidden behind the map or is it being pushed somewhere else on the page? You are missing a lot of essential information needed to assist with this, which may be why you got down-voted. Have you tried right-clicking on the page, and inspecting it to see what it's doing? If the site is live, or you are broadcasting the page in any way I could probably get it figured out.

Comment: The text appears below the map, I just want it to appear to the right of the map

Comment: putting together a code snippet to see what is going on...there's some html errors in here too...I'll get you setup

Comment: Ok...this should help you get in a better direction:
https://codepen.io/mattjackson4/pen/vaYPMY
I have changed everything to ID's as opposed to a mix of classes and id's...I also added a style sheet, so everything is proper.

Comment: @Yannik24 - did the codepen solution that I provided work out for you, or do you still need some assistance?

Comment: I just tried it, and it worked perfectly! I had to make a few adjustments with padding for aesthetics but otherwise thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `float: right;` to make text float to the right. `display: inline-block` also makes elements line up side by side.

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 50%;">Random text. Random text. Random text. Random text.</div>
<div style="width: 40%; float: right;">
<b>Text to the left.</b></div>
```

You can also use `right: 0px;` (with the position property set to make an element stick to the right).

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 50%;">Random text. Random text. Random text. Random text.</div>
<span style="position: absolute; right: 0px;">
<b>Text to the left.</b></span>
```

Comment: Although this is proper, the OP says that float: right; has been attempted to no avail.

Comment: @MattJackson Thanks for telling me. I have added another solution.

Comment: Just a side-note with the second solution, if the text is loading behind the map, you may consider adjusting the z-index. Here is a link that may help if this is part of the issue: https://tomelliott.com/html-css/css-position-child-div-parent

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: absolute;` and set `top` and `right` properties (how far away the element is from the top and the right of the page). Use `max-width` so the `iframe` does not overlap with the `div` with the text.

```html
<section id = "map">
<div class = "container">
<h2>Find Us Today!</h2>
<div class="mapouter">
<div class="gmap_canvas">
<iframe style="width:80%;" height="570" id="gmap_canvas" 
src="https://maps.google.com/maps? 
q=
5217%20Dominion%20Drive%20Dublin%2C%20VA%20&t=&z=13&ie=UTF8&iwloc=
&output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" 
marginwidth="0"></iframe>
<a href="https://www.embedgooglemap.net"></a>
</div>
<style = float.left>.mapouter{text- 
align:right;height:500px;width:600px;}.gmap_canvas 
{overflow:hidden;background:none!important;height:600px;width:600px;} 
</style>
</div>
</section>

<section id = "contact">
<div class = "container" style="position: absolute;right: 0;  top: 40px; max-width: 20%; overflow-wrap: break-word;">
<h3>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h3>
<p>5217 Dominion Drive <br>
  Dublin, Virginia, 24084<br>
  <br>

<h3>Contact Us</h3>
<p>(540)-XXXXXXXX</p>

<h3>Hours</h3>
<p>Monday: 9AM to 5PM<br>
 Tuesday: 9AM to 5PM<br>
 Wednesday: 9AM to 5PM<br>
 Thursday: 9AM to 5PM<br>
 Friday: 9AM to 5PM<br>
 Saturday: 9AM to 5PM<br>
 Sunday: 9AM to 5PM<br>
 </p>
 </div>
 </section>
```